# How to get the name of a xlink:href/svg id with scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am totally new to scrapy and just started yesterday to use it.
There is a page with ratings for products I want to get. Unfortunately the ratings are not texts but stars.
Let's say a product got two stars, it looks like this:

```
<div class="index-classRating">
  <div class="index-classIcon index-red">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full">
        #shadow-root (closed)
          <svg id="wci-starrating-full" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path d="1 2 3"></path>
          </svg>
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="index-classIcon index-red">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full">
        #shadow-root (closed)
          <svg id="wci-starrating-full" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path d="1 2 3"></path>
          </svg>
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

So I want to count how many stars aka "/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full" or "wci-starrating-full" are there.

So I tried

```
stars = response.xpath('//div[@class="index-classIcon index_red"]/svg[@viewBox="0 0 32 32"]/use[@xlink:href="/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full"]/svg/@id').extract()
```

and got an empty list.
But I want to have something like

```
stars = ["wci-starrating-full","wci-starrating-full"]
```

Answer (score 0):

viewbox must be written lowercase, "index_red" has dash not hyphen
try

```
stars=response.xpath('//div[@class="index-classIcon index-red"]/svg[@viewbox="0 0 32 32"]/use/svg/@id').extract()
```

Total example: (please copy-paste into python)

```
import scrapy
response=scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url='just_a_string',encoding='utf-8',body=u'''
<div class="index-classRating">
  <div class="index-classIcon index-red">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full">
        #shadow-root (closed)
          <svg id="wci-starrating-full" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path d="1 2 3"></path>
          </svg>
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="index-classIcon index-red">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <use xlink:href="/static/media/icons.f88ec073.svg#wci-starrating-full">
        #shadow-root (closed)
          <svg id="wci-starrating-full" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path d="1 2 3"></path>
          </svg>
      </use>
    </svg>
  </div>
''')
stars=response.xpath('//div[@class="index-classIcon index-red"]/svg[@viewbox="0 0 32 32"]/use/svg/@id').extract()
print(repr(stars))
```

Comment: I tried but when I

    print(stars)

I have stillan empty list

Comment: What do you mean with print(stars)? what if you print the repr of it with `print(repr(response.xpath('//div[@class="index-classIcon index-red"]/svg[@viewbox="0 0 32 32"]/use/svg/@id')))`

Comment: Wait a second! I think I forgot the "stars=" at the beginning. I thought it was clearer that way, but of course, that variable is not loaded then.

Comment: Holy Cow! What happens when you enter (see above):

Comment: By the way, there seems to be a </div> missing at the end, but that seems to cause no harm - on my Version of scrapy(1.5.1).

Comment: So I copied and run the total example and got a

TypeError: Cannot convert unicode body - HtmlResponse has no encoding

I checked my scrapy version which is 1.5.1 as well and added the missing  </div>

Comment: I added an 'u' in front of the http string. Scrapy is not running on my python3, so I used python2. Also, I added an encoding

Comment: Ok, now I can see the
`["wci-starrating-full","wci-starrating-full"]`

Comment: Then, something must be wrong with the http response object you called "response" in your question code. what does`print(repr(response.body))` say (when applied to YOUR source of "response")?